# SQLite Query for two tables.(Union All,Order By, Limit)

Tags: sqlite

TableMain

```
Task_Id  Task       Time     Date         Repetition    Snooze_Time
1        Meeting    22:59    23-3-2020    2             7
2        Meeting 2  20:40    22-3-2020    1             5 
3        Shopping   09:08    23-3-2020    3             3
```

TableRoutine

```
Task_Id  Task       Time     Repetition    Snooze_Time
1        GYM        13:28    2             7
```

My result Requirements:

1.Take data from table main where `Date` = "23-3-2020"

2.Date should be taken which is least comparing in both table.

3.Columns to have in result set:

"Task_Id  Task       Time     Repetition    Snooze_Time"

4.I need only one column (By use of Limit but don't know how?)(Suppose two tables have no time with same value)

```
Task_Id  Task       Time     Repetition    Snooze_Time
3        Shopping   09:08    3             3
```

EDIT: time column is store as text but has this format 07:05

Comment: Your expected results is the content of the second table.

Comment: In this scenario yes. But I give this data just for example. But in real situation can be different.

Comment: You should show us sample data that is representative enough of your use case, otherwise it is hard to really assess what you are looking for.

Comment: see now........

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? And what have you tried and what was the problem with it?

Comment: I don't know to write query for this...Actually I'm working on android studio and using sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Query :

```
Select Task_Id,Task,Time,Repetition,Snooze_Time from TableMain where Date = '23-3-2020' UNION ALL Select Task_Id,Task,Time,Repetition,Snooze_Time from TableRoutine order by Time Limit 1
```